# Dynamic Sitemap Diagram with Javascript

Tags: javascript, raphael

I have a list of pages with some connections from one page to another one.
I need to create a sitemap diagram that can automatic handle the position of the pages based on the connections between one element and another one, in order to avoid overlap of pages and connections.

Is there a javascript library that can handle this?

I need something like this because the sitemap is dynamic.

Comment: Got an example of the kind of output you are seeking?

Comment: d3.js has [*something*](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Gallery), I'm sure.

Comment: This d3.js example is pretty wow: [Flare imports hierarchical edge bundling](http://mbostock.github.com/d3/talk/20111116/bundle.html)

Comment: @JaredFarrish—cool page, completely fails in IE 8. I think the OP should look elsewhere.

Comment: Holy cow: http://mbostock.github.com/protovis/ Neat stuff. @RobG - In my reality distortion field, "completely fails" and "Internet Explorer" aren't necessarily separable. In all seriousness, though, whatever solution needs to be tested again requirements.

Comment: OHH! Totally forgot about [InfoVis Toolkit](http://thejit.org/demos/). *Specifically*, [Force Directed Static Graph](http://thejit.org/static/v20/Jit/Examples/ForceDirected/example1.html).

Comment: Since about half of IE users are on 8 or lower, there would need to be very specific non-functional requirements (e.g. a corporate environment with SOE that doesn't include IE 8 or lower) to ignore such IE users.